# UIImage moves right on rotation - wrong center point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, autolayout

When I rotate an image it moves right. It shouldn't. It seems like the center is set to the wrong point. See  screenshot: In both states - rotated and not - the center of the "+" shouldn't change.

[image]

I am positioning a UIImageView using auto layout like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...

addIconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AddCardIcon.png"]];
[addIconImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[addIconImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:addIconImageView];



[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[addIconImageView]-(10)-|"
                                                                  options:nil
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(addIconImageView)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-[addIconImageView]-|"
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(addIconImageView)]];

...
}
```

And here's what I do to rotate the image

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
                     addIconImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(addIconImageView.transform, M_PI/4);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }
 ];
```

How come the move right on rotation and how can I avoid it?

Comment: If the position of the image isn't (0,0), it will not rotate from it's center, but from the coordinate system's origin.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri He is adding a transformation on `addIconImageView` using `addIconImageView`'s coordinate system. What you mention would only be an issue if he used the super view's transform property.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that your image asset isn't perfectly square.

Resize AddCardIcon.png so that it has identical width and height and doesn't have any transparent padding on any side.

Otherwise, manually determine the center of the + and set [`addIconImageView.layer.anchorPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint)

Comment: the image is definitely square.

Comment: Is the center of the `+` actually in the exact center of the square image?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it's true the addIconImageView.center.x changes after the rotation (from 165.0 to 172.424622) but it really shouldn't. Hmm.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is addIconImageView.layer.anchorPoint set to?

Comment: it stays 0.50 all the time (even when the image is off to the right)